# R Shiny Dashboard (Refresh web page with updated records automatically every few mins or secs when in idle status)

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, page-refresh

R shiny dashboard got ui.R and Server.R file , trying to automatically refresh (equivalent to f5), the web app page every few minutes or seconds to fetch updated records from Source DB when the web app is kept in idle status

I have tried using a button its works fine ,but the requirement is to refresh page equivalent to f5 automatically

```
jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history. Go(0)}"
  useShinyjs(), 
        extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),                      # Add the js code to the page
        #actionButton("reset_button", "Reset Page")
```

Comment: Please have a look at `invalidateLater` to refresh data

Comment: Depending on the type of data you're interested in refreshing, you might want to try `reactiveFileReader`

Comment: Thanks Clemsang and TTL for the inputs provided , Invalidate Later worked for us to refresh my reports every few minutes to update from the source